# Can I manually invoke processing of window messages in the main thread in a win32 application?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I have a Win32 MFC application that does some processing in a loop. Currently the window stops redrawing while the loop is running. Can I somehow allocate time to the message queue inside my loop or will I have to move the processing to a different thread to free up the main thread for message handling?

Comment: Move the processing to a different thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code snippet to process messages:

```
MSG msg; 
if (::PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE)) 
{ 
    if (::GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) 
    {
        ::TranslateMessage(&msg); 
        ::DispatchMessage(&msg); 
    }
}
```

But it is always better to have separate thread for long operations to prevent blocking of main app thread.

Comment: Don't think that's enough in an MFC app. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dy7kd92.aspx

Comment: This may or may not be sufficient. For some applications, it's definitely missing a call to [IsDialogMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645498.aspx). It also fails to account for the `WM_QUIT` message. As posted this answer should not be the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. The processing that's going on is in a modal context so all I needed for the app to do while it was going on was to keep the window drawn and status bar up to date.

Comment: @BaldurGíslason: What about keyboard navigation in the modal UI? That breaks, when you apply the proposed solution.

Comment: Calling `PeekMessage()` and `GetMessage()` together is redundant. `MSG msg; while(::PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) { ... }`. Since you are just interested in drawing, consider using a `WM_PAINT` filter on `PeekMessage()`, or just get rid of the message loop completely and use [`UpdateWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145167.aspx) instead.

Comment: This is definitely not the right approach conceptually, and definitely the wrong implementation of that wrong approach in an MFC context.

Comment: This looks fine. There is no `while` loop, I am not sure if you need to check `WM_QUIT`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: You are right, there is no `while`-loop. But there should usually be one. After all, you want to handle **all** messages, that have piled up, not just one. Unless you want to risk running into the very situation, you set out to solve (an unresponsive UI). `WM_QUIT`  should, at the very least, terminate the processing loop. An interesting aspect (that I do not the answer to): Is the *"quit pending"*-flag removed, when you `PeekMessage` with `PM_NOREMOVE`?

Comment: @IInspectable I got confused because I was testing this in a loop which was running fake calculations (in order to simulate unresponsive behavior), so it worked by accident. However `PeekMessage` should have its own loop as you said. Following `PeekMessage(...PM_NOREMOVE)`, `GetMessage` returns zero upon seeing `WM_QUIT`. I guess it's easier to just use `PeekMessage(...PM_REMOVE)` Also I tested this with Windows 10 which is more forgiving towards unresponsive UI, I have to test it in older Windows versions.

Comment: EDGE CASE: If one of the messages you are processing sleeps or delays for a long time before finishing, sometimes Win32 will repost the message.  If you take this approach when that happens, you will probably get an infinite loop.